How to handle error in react-select using Formik
I'm working on a NextJs application using react-select within formik for form management and Yup for validation. I'm relatively new to these libraries and facing issues with handling errors specifically while I am trying to integrate react-select with formik.
I have a requirement where users should be able to select multiple options from a dropdown, but:
If no options are selected, it should show an error.
If more than two options are selected, it should also show an error.
Could someone guide me on how to integrate this error handling with react-select, formik and Yup effectively? Any help or codesandbox example code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here is the code
"use client";
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import makeAnimated from "react-select/animated";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Select = dynamic(() => import("react-select"), { ssr: false });

interface SpecialityOption {
  readonly value: string;
  readonly label: string;
}

const specialties: readonly SpecialityOption[] = [
  { value: "allergy_and_immunology", label: "Allergy and Immunology" },
  { value: "anesthesiology", label: "Anesthesiology" },
  { value: "biochemistry", label: "Biochemistry" },
  { value: "cardiology", label: "Cardiology" },
  { value: "cardiothoracic_surgery", label: "Cardiothoracic surgery" },
];

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  specializations: Yup.array()
    .required("You must select at least one specialization.")
    .max(2, "You cannot select more than two specializations.")
    .required("Specializations are required."),
});

const AddInfo = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-screen">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          specializations: [],
        }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          console.log(values);
          setSubmitting(false);
          // handle Submit here
        }}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting, setFieldValue, values }) => (
          <Form>
            <div className="py-2 px-4 border-t-[1px] border-gray-200 flex items-center">
              <label htmlFor="specializations">Specializations</label>
                  <Field name="specializations">
                    {({ field, form }: any) => (
              <Select
                styles={{
                  control: (provided, state) => ({
                    ...provided,
                    border: "none",
                    boxShadow: "none",
                  }),
                }}
                isMulti
                name="specializations"
                options={specialties}
                components={makeAnimated()}
                className="basic-multi-select w-full ml-4 outline-none border rounded"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                placeholder="Select specializations..."
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  setFieldValue("specializations", newValue);
                }}
              />
                    )}
                  </Field>
              <ErrorMessage
                name="specializations"
                component="div"
                className="ml-4 mt-2 text-xs text-red-500"
              />
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddInfo;
 

I tried to select more than two options or leave the selection empty, but no error messages were displayed.
